# How to resize an image array?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView iv_images;

    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageadapter1, null);

    iv_images = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_images1);

    iv_images.setImageResource(images[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9042060 byte
>   allocation with 8030424 free bytes and 7MB until OOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use libraries such as [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView iv_images;

    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageadapter1, null);

    iv_images = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_images1);

    Picasso.get()
       .load(images[position])
       .resize(YOUR_WIDTH, YOUR_HEIGHT)
       .centerCrop()
       .into(iv_images)

    return convertView;
}
```

Don't forgot to add dependecies.

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.picasso</groupId>
  <artifactId>picasso</artifactId>
  <version>2.71828</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Feel free to ask if you have questions about it.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Dude...It's Working

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a smaller image.

1. Google have actually published a guide on avoiding OutOfMemoryErrors [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) which will help a lot, though I had to use a smaller image size as well.
2. One method that will almost definitely work is to set **android:largeHeap="true"** in your **manifest**, between your **application** tags. This will increase your heap size, but may make your app lag a little.
3. Make use of **WebP** image for loading if you had large number of image.

You may, try this link
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Comment: plse check this link, https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap , may be help you